# Is Firestore a good choice to work with Node.JS in offline mode?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, raspberry-pi3

I created a simple Node.js program on my Raspberry Pi 3 that connects to a Google Cloud Firestore database. The goal is to have iOS and Android applications that will connect to the Firestore database at the same time.

When going offline and then online again, I see that all my requests for the database have been queued and then pushed to Cloud Firestore.

Here are my questions:

- Where are the requests saved?
- What is the limit of the queue?
- Is that queue configurable?
- Am I right saying that with Node.js+Firestore, there is no database saved locally to be able to work offline? Only with mobile or web apps, right?
- Any clue if Google will have that offline database for Node.js?
- With the goal that I want to achieve, does Firestore still make sense? If not, do you have suggestions?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Firestore is a good choice to work with Node.JS in offline mode?

According to the official documentation regarding [Firestore offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline):

> For the web, offline persistence is disabled by default. To enable persistence, call the enablePersistence method. Cloud Firestore's cache isn't automatically cleared between sessions. Consequently, if your web app handles sensitive information, make sure to ask the user if they're on a trusted device before enabling persistence.
>
> - **Important**: For the web, offline persistence is an experimental feature that is supported only by the Chrome, Safari, and Firefox web browsers. Also, if a user opens multiple browser tabs that point to the same Cloud Firestore database, and offline persistence is enabled, Cloud Firestore will work correctly only in the first tab.

So even if this offline persistence is an experimental feature, you can still use it in your projects. However, when using Node.js, offline persistence is not yet supported.

> Where are the requests are saved?

The Cloud Firestore database client keeps a copy of all data that you're listening to in memory. If you enable offline persistence, the client will also persist active and recent data to disk.

> What is the limit of the queue?

Please check my answer from the this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47752079/5246885)**.

> Does that queue is configurable?

No, it's not. It's all database or nothing.

> Am I right saying that with Node.js+Firestore, there is no database saved locally to be able to work offline? Only with mobile or web apps, right?

Yes you are. It only works for Android and iOS and web (experimental).

> Any clue if Google will have that offline database for Node.JS?

No, I don't. You should ask Firebase team for that.

> With the goal that I want to achieve, does Firestore still make sense? If not, do you have suggestions?

Because there is no support for offline persistence yet, I should consider using another database that can help you cache your data locally, when using Node.js

Comment: Hi @alex mamo, when activing the offline-persistence, I get 'unimplemented' error and I think it make sense based on available "languages". Don't forget, I am trying to use it within Node.js app.

Comment: I just saw it's for Node.js So please see my updated answer. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Mamo!

Comment: You're welcome, cheers!