# Enable Firebase offline persistence for web after Firebase object already being accessed

Tags: firebase, progressive-web-apps

**Encountered Error**

Trying to enable offline persistence for web after accessing Firebase methods outputs the following error:

```
You can only call enablePersistence() before calling any other methods on a Firestore object.
```

**Context:**

On initial PWA load user declined to enable offline support. So for this case I am looking for a possibilities to allow enable it afterwards.

**Personal thoughts:**
I believe it should be possible to force a re-render of app with the framework that is currently used and temporary store the flag that will ask firebase to enable offline support. But I wonder if there is some Firebase SDK offers a solution that provides a possibility to achieve that more elegant way.

**P.S**: 

Additionally I wonder once offline persistence option was enabled is it save to believe that offline persistence will be enabled each time user opens PWA unless the PWA related data was removed from the device

Answer (score 1):

Probably you mean Cloud Firestore, as Firebase has offline persistence only for mobile dev, not web.

As the error suggests, you should call `enablePersistance()` as first thing when you import/reference Firestore.

 I use it in an Angular application and I invoke it in my appModule:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, CardComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        AngularFireModule,

        AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence(),  <--

        AngularFireAuthModule,
        AngularFirestoreModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [{ provide: FirebaseOptionsToken, useValue: environment.firebaseConfig }],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Once offline persistance is enabled, Firestore will cache all accessed documents up to the defined cache limit (by default 40 MB, but you can change this value).
If the cache limit is reached, Firestore will prune the oldest documents.

If you want to learn more about enabling [full offline CRUD operations for PWAs, have a look at here](https://dev.to/paco_ita/break-the-cache-api-limits-in-our-pwa-oo3).

The cool thing is that all changes done while offline will be automatically synchronized with the server by Firestore, out of the box.

---

**UPDATE**

If your app deals with sensitive information and you want to provide extra security, then you have to find a way to workaround the Firestore requirements, willing to enable offline persistence as first method.
 Maybe then you should think to a way to remove the imported Firebase module and then importing it again with with `enablePersistence()`.

In Node.js for example:

```
var name = require.resolve('moduleName');

delete require.cache[name];
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've asked a question in the past https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57999550/why-enabling-offline-support-for-all-devices-isnt-recommended . According to it it's not generally recommended to enable offline support for web by default. So I promt an popup where I ask user if he or she trusts the device to enable it

Comment: But in case user declines it, I would like to offer a possibility in future to enable it from some sort of settings section of the application. So I wonder if there is a way to to do it after firestore object was already manipulated.