# Firestore avoid last write win behaviour

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an access control app for events. The tickets on those clients get synced ahead but I would like to store the current state in firestore, but they have to be updated in the correct order even if a device goes offline.
My question is based on [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47781502/3173572) which describe how the default "last write win" behavior works as well as [this explanation](https://youtu.be/oDvdAFP6OhQ?t=344). In the video he mentions that this can be changed by using security rules or cloud functions.

My approach with security rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /tickets/{ticket} {
      allow update: if request.resource.data.localTimestamp > resource.data.timestamp;
    }
  }
}
```

Does someone have a working example? Or an approach with cloud functions?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Or did you go another route?