# SQLiteDatabase entering infinite loop

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, android-sqlite, flutter-test

I got a strange behavior in my flutter app after running the app using **flutter run** which uses firebase firestone as a database; in fedora-terminal.

[image: This is the output I am getting after running the app]

Here is from where problem starts

[image: This is from where this starts]
I am not using SQLiteDatabase anywhere in the app. Can anyone please explain the issue and help me to solve the issue?

Comment: Do you specify [sqlflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) anywhere in your dependencies?

Comment: No, I don't even know about SQLite before this error, the app is running fine on windows.

Comment: I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47746100/how-reliable-is-firestore-as-an-offline-persistence-mechanism) and [this article](https://alexsaveau.dev/blog/firebase/android/survival-guide-how-to-migrate-from-the-firebase-realtime-database-to-cloud-firestore) regarding Firestore using SQLite on Android, which could explain the appearance of SQLite.

Comment: I understand the appearance but how can I solve it, as a regular linux user this creates a lot of problem.

Comment: Are you running you app in debug more? If so, do you get these messages when you dont?
Also if you are not using SQLite, are you using any other tools that might be using it?

Comment: I recently noticed something, this is happening only in android 7 phones which have RISC architecture. I don't have any tool related to SQLite.

Comment: The information currently available is not enough for me to reproduce or troubleshoot. Please add more context on what exactly you are doing/using and further logging and debugging messages to see where this issue is starting.

Comment: I now had added the snip from where the problem initiates

Comment: Is this stopping the application from working? 

As SQLite is used by Firestore when offline, I'm guessing this only happens when testing offline, can you confirm this?

Also, please add the logs and code as text and not images, this makes it easier to copy and paste.